# How can I read a file that contains a list of dictionaries into python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've created a file that contains a list of dictionaries that I was working with. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to re-import that file back into python in that same format.

I initially wrote the file out as JSON and as text, like this:

```
d = list_of_dics
jsonarray = json.dumps(d)

with open('list_of_dics.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(jsonarray, outfile)

with open('list_of_dics.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(jsonarray, outfile)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to re-import these into python in the same format — i.e., a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Just a guess here, but usually if a library supplies an "encode" to json function (`.dump` in this case), it also supplies a "decode" from json function. Have you checked the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) incorrectly. You should be passing `d` to it directly, not the output of `json.dumps(d)`. Once you do that, you can use [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) to retrieve your data.

```
with open('list_of_dics.txt', 'r') as infile:
    d = json.load(infile)
```

Comment: Ah, gotcha — that's why I was getting an odd output. To clarify, though — using `json.load(infile)` gives me a unicode string. Is there any way to load this directly as a list of dics?

Comment: Nevermind, got it — just need to remove the `"` from the start and end of the list to un-screw up the formatting. Using the method above works perfectly then.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
json.dumps(d)
```

you've (JSON-)encoded list `d` in a string (which you assign to a variable misleadingly called `jsonarray`).

With

```
json.dump(jsonarray, outfile)
```

you've JSON-encoded that *string* and written the result to `outfile`.

So it's now (unnecessarily) doubly JSON-encoded in the files `list_of_dics.txt` and `list_of_dics.json`.

To *cleanly* get it back from there (without resorting to [manual string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539001/how-can-i-read-a-file-that-contains-a-list-of-dictionaries-into-python#comment58767053_35539058)) you have to decode it twice:

```
import json

with open('list_of_dics.json', 'r') as infile:
    recovered_d = json.loads(json.load(infile))
```